# DTD won't verify

Tags: xml, dtd

I am trying to learn XML and DTD , I just went through w3c tutorial for DTD, and trying to implement a recipe scenario in XML using DTD, this is what wrote in the DTD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ENTITY  RECIPE (NAME,INGREDIENTS,INSTRUCTIONS) >
<!ENTITY NAME ("Baking Powder Biscuits") >
<!ENTITY  INGREDIENTS SYSTEM "Ingredients.dtd"  >
<!ENTITY  INSTRUCTIONS SYSTEM "Instructions.dtd" >

<!ATTLIST RECIPE UNITS "16 BISCUITS" #FIXED>
```

When I try to verify ,the parses gives me a error in line 2 saying open quot missing in decl,can't undesrstand whats wrong, please help.

Thanks

This is xml file 'recipe':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE RECIPE SYSTEM "recipe.dtd">
```

This is recipe dtd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ENTITY  RECIPE NAME INGREDIENTS,INSTRUCTIONS>
<!ENTITY NAME "Baking Powder Biscuits" >
<!ENTITY  % INGREDIENTS SYSTEM "Ingredients.dtd"  >
<!ENTITY  % INSTRUCTIONS SYSTEM "Instructions.dtd" >

<!ATTLIST RECIPE UNITS CDATA #FIXED "16 BISCUITS" >
```

this is other dtd ingreduents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ENTITY  INGREDIENTS  ("2 cups flour","1 tablespoon sugar", "1/2 teaspoon salt", "1/2 cup vegetable shortening", "4 teaspoon baking powder", "2/3 cup milk")>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an ENTITY declaration for `RECIPE`, but it looks like it should be an ELEMENT declaration (based on the model and the ATTLIST for RECIPE):

```
<!ELEMENT RECIPE (NAME,INGREDIENTS,INSTRUCTIONS) >
```

The `NAME` ENTITY declaration looks like it really should be an ENTITY, but you need to remove the parentheses:

```
<!ENTITY NAME "Baking Powder Biscuits">
```

Also, the two ENTITY declarations that point to the .dtd files should be [parameter entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#dt-PE) if they actually contain additional declarations:

```
<!ENTITY % INGREDIENTS SYSTEM "Ingredients.dtd"  >
<!ENTITY % INSTRUCTIONS SYSTEM "Instructions.dtd" >
```

You would reference them with `%INGREDIENTS;` and `%INSTRUCTIONS;`.

The ATTLIST for RECIPE is also incorrect. For a fixed value, try this:

```
<!ATTLIST RECIPE UNITS CDATA #FIXED "16 BISCUITS">
```

Comment: no ,I tried your steps , also removed the references completely ,but still there is the error, BTW I am using oxygen editor for validating

Comment: @Snedden27 - The only other issue I see is your attribute declaration (assuming the element declarations for NAME,INGREDIENTS, and INSTRUCTIONS are in the other .dtd files). Try this instead: `<!ATTLIST RECIPE UNITS CDATA #FIXED "16 BISCUITS">`

Comment: @Snedden27 - Can you add an updated version of your DTD to your question?

Comment: K wait I would try to add all the files

Answer (score 1):

Your document type definition files are not XML document instances; they should not begin with XML declarations.  Once you delete the XML declarations from them, you will run into the problems identified by Daniel Haley.

Comment: Good catch on the XML declarations. +1